# Trying to refer a Reusbale Workflow from a Private repo

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to find a workaround for using a Reusable workflow between two private repos: (It is not supported natively)

Context: I am trying to use a central repo (private) to contain all the Workflows and refer to that location from other repos (private).

Legend:
Central Repo: Contains all the Reusable Workflows. (If we edit a file in here we should not have to edit each and every repo's workflow files)
Calling Repo: A repo which runs Workflows, This repo will try to refer the workflows from the Central repo.

```
name: Calling Reusable Workflows

on: [ push ]

jobs:
  download-remote-repo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Get private repo with action
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: kalanatd/central-repo
        ref: main
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
    - name: List Files After remote Checkout
      run: |
        pwd
        ls -a                 // I can see the checked out remote repo files in here
        ls -al .github/workflows
        cat ./.github/workflows/workflow.yml             // Can read the file without any issue
    - name: Run a workflow file
      uses: ./.github/workflows/workflow.yml
```

Note: In aboe scenario ./.github/workflows/workflow.yml is dynamically checked out to the Runner's workspace. Even though 'run' commands can see that file 'uses' command does not use it.

[1] Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/caller-repo/caller-repo/workflow.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?

[2] https://github.github.io/actions-cheat-sheet/actions-cheat-sheet.pdf

Note:

I learned that RWs can not be called under `steps` which means there is no way to download a RW from another place and use that workflow, right?

Comment: It's supported on Organization, but not on Personal accounts. If those 2 private repos are on the same organization, it would be possible to do it without any workaround. Is that an option here?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Actually these two repos are in the same organization.  Both of them are private. Please note that we are not using Github Enteprise Plan, but the Github Teams plan. I could not find any method for this, If you can guide me or a give me some tips that would be really helpful.

Comment: Hmm, according to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-enterprise) it seems this solution only works for the enterprise plan, not for the team plan. In that case, you would need [the reusable workflow to be in a public repository](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#access-to-reusable-workflows), but that won't attend your scenario.

Comment: Regarding the error you shared, it's because you're calling the reusable workflow as you call an action. The syntax is different. [This is an example for reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#passing-inputs-and-secrets-to-a-reusable-workflow), and [this is an example of how to call an action from a different repo](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-inside-a-different-private-repository-than-the-workflow)

Comment: A workaround could actually be to call an action from a private repository to perform what you want (the [second example in the previous comment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-inside-a-different-private-repository-than-the-workflow) above). However doing this you will have to set the runner and the inputs in the first workflow (that's a bit different than a reusable workflow when you can specify which runner to use for all call without exposing it in the original workflow).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed guide and insight @GuiFalourd! Really appreciate it. I decided to use a job to sync workflow directories from the central repo and then run them as local workflow files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to find a workaround for using a Reusable workflow between two private repos: (It is not supported natively)

Actually... it is, at least on GitHub (and later on a private GHE instance)

> ### [GitHub Actions – Sharing actions and reusable workflows from private repositories is now GA](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-12-14-github-actions-sharing-actions-and-reusable-workflows-from-private-repositories-is-now-ga) (Dec. 2022)
>
> The actions and reusable workflows from private repositories can now be shared with other private repositories within the same organization, user account, or enterprise.

See [managing the repository settings](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository) and [managing the enterprise repository settings](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository) to allow access to workflows in other repositories.

> We have also added the API support to configure Actions share policy.
> Refer to [API support](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/permissions#get-the-level-of-access-for-workflows-outside-of-the-repository) or [API support for Enterprise](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/actions/permissions#get-the-level-of-access-for-workflows-outside-of-the-repository) for more details.
>
> Learn more about [Sharing actions and workflows from your private repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-from-your-private-repository), [Sharing actions and workflows with your organization](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-organization), and [Sharing Actions and workflows with your enterprise](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-enterprise).